# AWS Device Farm Get list of available devices

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, testing, aws-device-farm

I see AWS Lists down available devices on this portal
http://awsdevicefarm.info/ 
There is devices.js file that loads in this page that is essentiallly a json string containing details of devices.

I want to know is there a API call by which I can find list of all available devices in AWS Device farm. I am not able to locate that API.

Comment: Hi, can you let me know if my answer helped at all? Feel free to let me know if there are additional questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [list-devices API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_ListDevices.html) which will return a list of device type available in the public offering. However, it's not possible to list specific device instances if you're looking for a device with a specific UDID value.

HTH

-James